# SQL Server CE Download

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the latest version of SQL Server CE?  And what is the download link?  I Googled and the link I got there is not working.  I would prefer a stand alone installation and not part of Webmatrix.  Is this possible?

I would like to use it for my testing in ASP.NET MVC 3.

I know this is not a programming question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abe has linked to SQL Server CE 3.5 which is probably your best stable choice. However 4 is now out ([ScottGu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx)) and you can download it from here

- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2)

or through WebMatrix - although the VS2010 tooling is in the service pack which is still in beta.